# How to auto reload python module without restarting app?

Tags: python, django, reload

I am interested in adapting python file after I run the app. Suppose we have a script:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    print(2)
```

I run it, so it prints number `2` every 10 seconds.
I would like to be able to change `2` to `5` so that I don't need to rerun script, but output changed to `5.`

This mechanism is somehow implemented in `Django`, after file is edited, data on server is reloaded.

Edit:

```
import time
from importlib import reload
import data

while True:
    reload(data)
    print(data.some_data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

something like this would do the job, but maybe there is better way of achieving such behaviour?

Comment: What specifically does this have to do with django?

Comment: It does not have to do anything with Django. Django was a example of reloading files while script is running, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a seperate file to manage dynamic content. And then import the data that you need from that file.

data.py

```
some_data = 10
```

script.py

```
import time
from .data import some_data

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    print(some_data)
```

and then you can just edit the value in data.py to whatever value you want without restarting the script.

Comment: Does not work. It somehow directed me to working solution, but still it's pretty ugly